# Хранение и обмен данными между background scripts и content_scripts в Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, manifest

**Манифест:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Bot for roulette",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "auto game with default strategy",
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_title": "Options", 
        "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background":
    {
        "scripts":
        [
            "js/jquery.js",
            "js/mytrades.js",
            "js/xdFileStorage.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": ["http://xxx.ru/"],

    "content_scripts":
    [{
        "js":
        [
            "js/jquery.js",
            "js/myoffers.js",
            "js/xdFileStorage.js"
        ],
        "matches": [ "http://xxx.ru/" ]
    }]
}
```

**Файл popup.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/mytrades.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="bet" placeholder="2" style="height: 22px; width: 125px; float: left;">
```

Когда я открываю страницу `xxx.ru` - на ней начинает работать `myoffers.js`.
Но все настройки моего приложение находятся в файле  `mytrades.js` (Такие как: время обновления данных на странице, и сохранение еще одного параметра(true or false)).

Сначала я сделал в `mytrades.js` запись в куки, но, оказывается в файле `myoffers.js` эти куки получить нельзя.

Ну и сам вопрос: Как мне сохранить данные допустим из input куда-то, что-бы можно было прочесть в `mytrades.js` ?

Comment: Вот хорошая статья на хабре: https://habr.com/post/174745/ . Смотреть примеры 1, 2, 3 и 4 в середине статьи. Я как прочитал, так сразу всё понял!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Хроме нет такого способа хранения, что бы информация была доступна и в контенте и в бакграунде. Единственный способ взаимодействия бакграунда с контентом - это сообщения.
В бакграунде создаете обработчик сообщений, примерно так:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(req, sender, response)
  {
   if(req.type=='getInfo') response({ok:"ok", info:"info ...", ....});
  }
);
```

У обработчика сообщений 3 параметра: `req` - запрос, может быть чем угодно, что вызывающая сторона передаст - то и придет. Наиболее удобно передавать объект, т.к. в него легко уложить любые параметры и данные которые мы хотели бы передать. `req.type` - Это для примера, обработчик сообщений один и он должен как то разделить разнообразные запросы поступающие извне. `sender` - объект, тот кто послал запрос, из интересных данных в нем есть `tab` - Id таба из которого пришло сообщение. Некоторые сообщения могут быть не из табов - тогда его не будет. `response` - посылающий событие может объявить функцию - обработчик ответов, вот это она и есть и ее вызов - один из двух способов вернуть как то информацию, второй способ - посылка ответного сообщения. Параметр - опять же что угодно, что будет передано вызывающему, опять же лучше всего использовать объект.

В контенте посылаете сообщение примерно так:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'getInfo'}, function(ret)
 {
  if(!ret) {console.log("Error send message "+chrome.runtime.lastError); return;}
  if(ret.ok=='ok') console.log(ret.info);
 });
```

Тут всего 2 параметра: передаваемый объект с данными запроса и функция - обработчик ответа. Если функция обработчик вызвана, а ее параметр false - то значит ответа никто не посылал или его некому было посылать (нет обработчика сообщений). Это важный момент для ботов, если сообщение посылает наоборот - бакграунд, а в вызываемом табе не прогрузилась страница и не запустился контент скрипт. Возможно был сбой сервера или сети и там висит какая нибудь 404 страница без вашего контент скрипта. Обработав эту ошибку бакграунд может принять решение - перегрузить страницу в табе или открыть какой то нужный url в ней. Хотя иногда обработчик может быть не вызван никогда, это обрабатывать можно только таймаутами.

Все происходит асинхронно, `sendMessage` не будет приостанавливать выполнение остальной части вашего скрипта на время пока бакграунд отвечает. Как ответит - запустится обработчик ответа.

Аналогичным образом контент может объявить свой обработчик сообщений и получать сообщения посланные явно бакграундом или другими контент скриптами на других открытых страницах браузера.

Для обратного взаимодействия бакграунд-контент используется `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` которому первым параметром передается `tabId` того таба в который надо отправить событие, потом так же объект-запрос и функция обработчик ответов. И там еще есть необязательный параметр - дополнительных опций, описание в документации по [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)

Comment: С Новым годом Вас и огромное Вам спасибо !