# Как выполнить скрипт, в той вкладке браузера в которой мы находимся, из popup меню , расширения

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Как выполнить скрипт, в той вкладке браузера в которой мы находимся, из popup меню , расширения?

Когда я нажимаю на расширение, открывается попап меню, там есть кнопка, которая вызывает скрипт. Но, этот скрипт должен выполняться на той странице в которой мы находимся, а не в popup.html . Как так сделать? 
Если я этот скрипт через консоль вставляю, все отрабатывает. То есть как получить доступ к странице что бы там можно было выполнить скрипт в её окружении? У меня там ratiobutton (на веб-старницы к которой будет применяться плагин) и хочу их просто включать через скрипт.

**вот мой манифест**

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "2",
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "description": "Test!",
  "icons": {
    "16" : "images/GB-19.png",
    "48" : "images/GB-48.png",
    "128" : "images/GB-128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/GB-19.png",
    "default_title": "TestExam",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs","activeTab"]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>UniversityExam</title>
</head>




<body>



    <div class='b-menu'>

        <form action="#" onsubmit="return clik2();" name="myForm">
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">a<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="b">b<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="c">c<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="d">d<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="e">e<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="f">f<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="g">g<Br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="h">h
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Заполнить" ></p>
        </form>

    </div>  


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // для теста 
        function clik2() {
            //console.log("Получилось - ");
            //document.wrtite("jj")
            document.body.bgColor="red";
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: popup не доступна текущая страница ни в каком виде. Вам надо сделать content script, который будет загружен на этой странице и общаться с этим скриптом через сообщения (см. chrome.runtine.onMessage, chrome.runtime.sendMessage, chrome.tabs.sendMessage) Из контент скрипта вы получите доступ к текущему document таба на котором он загрузился, но при этом не получите доступ к JS коду самой страницы, но вот это последнее ограничение в принципе обойти можно, только обычно не нужно

Comment: Mike А Как?  Что то у меня с попала не получается обзаться через эти сообщения.

Comment: Вот, на днях отвечал на похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479302/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-background-scripts-%D0%B8-content-scripts-%D0%B2-chrome-ext/479303#479303  У вас вместо бакграунда попап. связь практически такая же. только попап должен искать текущую страницу чем то вроде `chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow: true}, function...)`

Comment: Во, нашел, даже круче есть https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Comment: Mike из попапа даже console.log("Получилось - "); не работает. Почему?

Comment: executeScript - я про это читал уже. Но куда его и где управлять этим, не ясно.

Comment: Для чего попап если из него ничего не работает?

Comment: Отлично из него все работает. просто информацию в сам popup.html выводите, хоть document.wrtite()  просто у него своя консоль, а не та которая у таба и вы ее не видите. что из чата убежали я там отвечать начал

Comment: @Mike -Странно. У меня даже цвет элемента не меняется.  Хотя скрипт работает на обычной странице.  function clik2() {
            document.body.bgColor="red";
        }

Comment: А вы click2() то вызвать не забываете :)

Comment: @Mike - В каком смысле , не понял?)  Если открыть через браузер, то все работает. а если установить плагин, и попытаться там изменить цвет body.bgColor самого попапа, то ничего не поисходит.

Comment: document.body.bgColor="red"; в попапе по идее должен покрасить в красный сам попап. только пока не делайте его в функции. а просто так положите, а то не ясно как вы в документе вызываете click2 и как это делаете в попапе

Comment: @Mike -  Я в ответе привел код, как я меняю цвет на красный.

Comment: @Mike - Не работает , даже если не вызывать через функцию  <form action="#" onsubmit="return document.body.bgColor=&quot;red&quot;;" name="myForm">

Comment: @Mike - похоже строчные скрипты нельзя использовать в попапе. А я мучался МиРXsDFr.....

Answer (score 1):

Ниже пример, в попапе открываем консоль и вводим window.opener.message()

http://jsfiddle.net/xct0x0rv/

html

```
<a class="a">window</a>
```

js

```
window.message = function(message){
    alert('message from child window: '+message);
}
window.popup = function(){
    window.open("","mywindow","");
}

$('a').click(popup);
```